# Is validates_presence_of the preferred technique to require a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

Basically: My model requires at least one instance of an associated model be present.  Should I use `validates_presence_of` to assert this validation, or should I write some custom validation code?

Here are the essentials of my model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  validates_presence_of :channels, :message => "can't be empty"
end
```

(I assume things would be the same if I used `has_many` in place of `has_and_belongs_to_many`.)

Instead of the `validates_presence_of` line I could do this:

```
def validate
  errors.add(:channels, "can't be empty") if channels.size < 1
end
```

I replaced the latter with the former in the Rails app I'm working on and am wondering if there might be any problems.

So to be more sure, I wrote the following rspec coverage, and both implementations respond the same:

```
describe Event do
  before do
    @net = Factory.create(:network)
    @net_config = Factory.create(:network_config, :network => @net)
  end
  it "must have a channel" do
    e = Factory.build(:event, :network => @net, :channels => [])
    e.should have(1).error_on(:channels)
  end    
end
```

That is, if I remove the validation code, the above spec fails; if I put in either version of the validation code, the above spec passes.

So I might assume that my new implementation is ok.  But I've read that `validates_presence` triggers a database load which, in turn, would wipe out any in-memory objects constructed from nested attributes.  The `proxy_target method`, on the other hand, will return the in-memory objects without triggering a load.  Some links on `proxy_target`: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy http://withoutscope.com/2008/8/22/don-t-use-proxy_target-in-ar-association-extensions

In my particular case I'm not using `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but I wonder if I need to be cautious about this.